# CartThrob Per User Limit Discount and Logged Out Useres

Tags: cartthrob, discounts

I'm trying to setup a discount in CartThrob so members can get 10% off their order. This works gang busters for those members but, for logged out members, the discount shows up and is applied. Is there a way to have a User Limit Discount *not* apply to logged out members?

Answer (score 2):

To get around this, you just have to ensure that there is a value of zero (0) in the Redeemed by list. Mine now looks something like this:

1|4|39|0|6

(Note that 0 above).